# How to avoid use of medium strength ciphers in WAS liberty server with openJDK 1.8

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, cipher

Good day,

I have a IBM WAS liberty server, which is place under OS `redhat linux`, with `openjdk` version 1.8.0_242.

I receive a `pentest` report that complain about this server is using medium strength ciphers. And the `pentest` report also recommend me to use `TLS 1.2` with `AES-GCM` suites or higher instead.

Currently my server only enable TLSv1.2.

First thing I would like to ask is how can I disable/remove the medium strength ciphers in my server?

Second thing is, I would like to know how can I check whether this server is using medium strength ciphers. So that I can know anything I changes have disable/remove the medium strength ciphers or not.

I have try `openssl` command as follow:

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.7.5.65:9443 -tls1_2
```

The result I get is as follow:

```
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1710 bytes and written 479 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

I saw the `DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256` in the result, but is this to show that my server is using medium strength cipher?

Another way is the way I refer to this post [How do I list the SSL/TLS cipher suites a particular website offers?](https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers) , I run the script, its showing my cipher 1 by 1 and tell me whether it have ssl handshake failure or not, possible to know whether this server having medium strength cipher from here?

I have try something also, 1 of it is I edit the jvm java.security, to remove the `3DES_EDE_CBC` in `jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms`, I restart server, but also same result for the `openssl s_client -connect 10.7.5.65:9443 -tls1_2` command, thus I am not sure whether it fix the thing or not.

Kindly help and advise.

Comment: you can explicitly disable algorithms in java.security file  like: *jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,  DES, DESede, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224*

Comment: Hi @kofemann, I will do that now. May I know how can I verify that my server's cipher is no more medium strength? Because I would like to check the result before and after my changes on the java.security file.

Comment: There are plenty of online and offline tools that can help you, for example /bin/bash based SSL/TLS tester: testssl.sh
https://testssl.sh/

Comment: @kofemann, your comment solve my issue. Before this I am just disable in `jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms`, found that its not take effect, after I apply changes in `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, and its work. You can write it as answer, and I will mark it as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many application servers have they own configuration properties to disable weak chipher suites. However, you can enforce the policy on JRE level. The property *jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms* in *java.security* file can be used to disable specific algorithms. For example:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, DES, DESede, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 768, EC keySize < 224
```

Finally, when desired security configuration is in place, you can use one of the online services, like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html, or offline tools, like https://testssl.sh/ to validate our setup.